# What UI framework does LightTable use?

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I'm learning clojure and am using LightTable. Since it's also built in clojure I'd like to know which UI framework it's using, but can't find it in the [source](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable).

Can anyone tell me which UI framework it's using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light Table uses [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and renders its UI as HTML using ClojureScript.  It uses Chris Granger's [crate](https://github.com/ibdknox/crate) (a ClojureScript version of Hiccup) for HTML templating.

Comment: How about the actual window chrome? Is that provided by node-webkit?